# JPA - update entity with one to many relationship array list

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Supposed I'm updating my user entity which has a one to many relationship with post

this is the code for update

```
public User updateUser(Long userid, Userdto userdto) {
    User user = findByTemplatesFooterNo(userid);
    User mappedUser = modelmapper.map(UserDto, User.class);

    user.setName(mappedUser.getName());
    user.setAge(mappedUser.getAge());

    user.getPosts().clear();
    user.getPosts().addAll(mappedUser.getPost());

    userrepository.save(user);
}
```

this is the current data of User

```
{
  "user_id" : 1,
  "name" : "testname",
  "age" : "testage",
  "posts" : [
       {
            "post_id" : 1,
            "title" : "titlepost",
            "content" : "content"
       },
       {
            "post_id" : 2,
            "title" : "titlepost",
            "content" : "content"
       },
  ]
}
```

this is what I pass on request body to update the user with an Id of 1

```
{
  "name" : "testname",
  "age" : "testage",
  "posts" : [
       {
            "title" : "titlepost",
            "content" : "content"
       }    
  ]
}
```

I can successfully update the user and the response is

```
{
  "user_id" : 1,
  "name" : "testname",
  "age" : "testage",
  "posts" : [
       {
            "post_id" : 3,
            "title" : "titlepost",
            "content" : "content"
       }    
  ]
}
```

It replaces all the current post. What I want is just to append the new so that the response will become

```
{
      "user_id" : 1,
      "name" : "testname",
      "age" : "testage",
      "posts" : [
           {
                "post_id" : 1,
                "title" : "titlepost",
                "content" : "content"
           },
           {
                "post_id" : 2,
                "title" : "titlepost",
                "content" : "content"
           },
           {
                "post_id" : 3,
                "title" : "titlepost",
                "content" : "content"
           },
      ]
}
```

**User entity**

```
 @OneToMany(
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY
 )
 @JoinColumn(
            name = "user_id",
            foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_post_id"),
            referencedColumnName = "userId"
 )
 private List<Post> post = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: You need to fetch user by id (1) , compare and  save back whole object

Comment: what do you mean by compare? im fetching the user by id 1

Comment: Correct, Fetch user by Id for existing posts. Compare existing **posts** with incoming post. Append it to existing List<Post> if incoming post is new(comparison may say doesn't exist) and save whole user object again

Comment: any example to start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You explicitly call `user.getPosts().clear()` and yet you are surprised that only the new post exists?

You also need to be aware that `userrepository.save(user)` returns the merged result and you need to return that from your method to have an up-to-date representation serialized to JSON.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html?is-external=true#save-S-

> Saves a given entity. **Use the returned instance for further operations**
>   as the save operation might have changed the entity instance
>   completely.

Changes:

```
public User updateUser(Long userid, Userdto userdto) {
    User user = findByTemplatesFooterNo(userid);
    User mappedUser = modelmapper.map(UserDto, User.class);

    user.setName(mappedUser.getName());
    user.setAge(mappedUser.getAge());

    //user.getPosts().clear(); <-- WHY?
    user.getPosts().addAll(mappedUser.getPost());

    return userrepository.save(user); // <-- return the result of the merge
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is when i update a specific id in post it will not update and will have an error because the post will be save twice with same id, thats why i need to clear it first? Before saving

Comment: Okay, so you should have asked a question about that rather than your perceived solution. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 0):

`user.getPosts().addAll(mappedUser.getPost());`

As far I know Hibernate recommends using Collection interface for one to many relations.
in this way method, addAll will not merge existing posts elements with the news.
As a result, you will have duplicate posts in the collection.
addAll will work only in case if you 100% sure that mappedUser contains only new elements. But if it is not true then you will need to **merge manually** or clear previous collection to avoid duplication. Clear collection **is not recommended**. Because clear means that hibernate will delete all records and then create it again.

Only in case you choose Set like collection your way will works.
But it **is not recommended** as well, because of set require to calculate hashcode. To do it hibernate will need to get all records from a database.
Imagine a situation you have 3000 posts for one user. And you add a new one to set... Hibernate will need to get all 3000 posts to be sure that new one is unique.